# getting the correct return type from typed function fails

Tags: scala

I am trying to get proper type with a typed function e.g

```
sealed trait Pet
case object Dog extends Pet
case object Cat extends Pet
case object Fish

def getPet[P >: Pet](pet: P) : P = {
  pet match{
    case Dog => Dog
    case Cat => Cat
  }
}

val d: Dog = getPet(Dog)//not compiled
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Well, in this case there are two simple problems. - 1 `P >: Pet` means any type `P` that is a **super type** of `Pet`. I am pretty sure you want `P <: Pet`, which means any type `P` that is a **subtype** of `Pet`. - 2 `Dog` is not really a _type_, the _type_ of the singleton instance `Dog` is `Dog.type`. - With that 2 changes, everything compiles... However, in general this is a complex problem, usually the simple alternative is **F-Bounded polymorphism**, but that has some limitations / problems. And the usual recommended solution is **typeclasses**. - If you want, share your real use case.

Comment: What's `Dog` in `getPet(Dog)`? You can pass a value to a function. I don't see the value `Dog` ever defined.

Comment: @mfirry `Dog` refers to the case object.

Comment: @mfirry Is defined there, in the second line of the snippet.

Comment: It's funny that for case classes `case class Dog() extends Pet`
`case class Cat() extends Pet` `def getPet[P <: Pet](pet: P) : P = {
    pet match{
      case Dog() => Dog();
      case Cat() => Cat()
    }
  }` doesn't compile but for case objects `case object Dog extends Pet`
`case object Cat extends Pet` `def getPet[P <: Pet](pet: P) : P = {
      pet match{
        case Dog => Dog;
        case Cat => Cat
      }
    }` `val d: Dog.type = getPet(Dog)` compiles.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a *typeclass* example

```
sealed trait Pet
case object Dog extends Pet
case object Cat extends Pet
case object Fish extends Pet

trait PetFactory[P <: Pet] {
  def getPet(p: P): P
}

object PetFactory {
  def getPet[P <: Pet](p: P)(implicit petFactory: PetFactory[P]): P = petFactory.getPet(p)
  implicit val dogFactory: PetFactory[Dog.type] = (dog: Dog.type) => dog
  implicit val catFactory: PetFactory[Cat.type] = (cat: Cat.type) => cat
  implicit val fishFactory: PetFactory[Fish.type] = (fish: Fish.type) => fish
}

import PetFactory._

getPet(Dog)
getPet(Cat)
getPet(Fish)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Dog.type = Dog
res1: Cat.type = Cat
res2: Fish.type = Fish
```

Note that the type of singleton object `O` is `O.type`, for example

```
val fish: Fish.type = Fish
```